# How to set curl into php

Tags: php, forms, curl

This is my form.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <label class="form-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input class="user" type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email Id</label>
    <input class="email" type="email" name="email" id="email">
</form>
```

How can I set this curl code into php for this form?

Create a new User
Users can be created or updated via a POST method to `https://api.intercom.io/users`, which accepts a JSON object describing the user.

Example request:

```
curl https://api.intercom.io/users \
  -X POST \
  -u app_id:api_key \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
  {
  "email": "hello@projectmap.io"
  }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work,

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $url = 'https://api.intercom.io/users';
    $array=array('email'=>$_POST['email']);
    $headers = array(
                        'Accept: application/json',
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($array));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'app_id:api_key');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: what else i need to do in form?

Comment: @SirenBrown Your form section includes two inputs, name and email can you tell me are you using name field?

Comment: yes name and email as name field to send mail in php.

Comment: @SirenBrown but in the above curl request you have mentioned does not include name field it includes only email.. I am altering my answer for email.